# How to add a simple drop down in rails for pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, pagination

I used will_paginate to paginate, now I want to control how many records in one page.
I do know how to interact data from the select_tag. please tell me how to return the data to 
@page in controller.

I used

```
<td><%= select_tag "count", "<option>10</option> <option>20</option>".html_safe%></td>
```

Controller

```
def index
  @page = 10;
  @users = User.order(:username).joins(:biography).where("`is_active?` = true AND `last_sign_in_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @page)
end
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code where you are doing the pagination?

Comment: Depending upon on the selected value in `select_tag`,you want to set the records per page right? then you can pass `params[:count]` to `per_page` option like this `:per_page => params[:count]`

Comment: Or you can change `@page` to `@page = params[:count]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `params[:count]` like this to get the number of records per page based on the `value selected` in the `select_tag`

```
def index
  @page = params[:count] #here
  @users = User.order(:username).joins(:biography).where("is_active? = true AND last_sign_in_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @page)
end
```